# how to use for loop to read data from mysql table

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, for-loop

I have mysql Database and i want to read data from there in my web application with for loop instead of foreach loop.

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();

string query = "SELECT * FROM survey ORDER BY datetime DESC";
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

com.CommandTimeout = 0;
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
da.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();            

foreach (DataRow item in ds.Rows)
{
    string unique = item.ItemArray[4].ToString();
    var sur = db2.VoipSurveys.Where(a => a.UniqueId == unique).SingleOrDefault();
    if (sur == null)
    {
        VoipSurvey vs = new VoipSurvey()
        {
            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ItemArray[1]),
            Point = Convert.ToInt32(item.ItemArray[2]),
            CallerId = item.ItemArray[3].ToString(),
            UniqueId = item.ItemArray[4].ToString(),
            AgentNumber = item.ItemArray[5].ToString(),
            AgentName = item.ItemArray[6].ToString(),
            QueueNumber = item.ItemArray[7].ToString()
        };

        db2.VoipSurveys.Add(vs);
        db2.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

I need reading data from specific index like reading data in mysql table from this Date until now. and i think my problem would be solved with for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [DataView RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.7.2) also:

```
  // Create a DataView
  DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
  dv.RowFilter = " (Date >= #" +
  Dateyouwanttouse +
  "# And Date <= #" +
  DateTime.Now +
  "# ) ";
```

Simply do this:

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
{
    DataRow row = rowView.Row;
    // Do something //
}
```

Comment: thank your for your answer. what should i do after this code? i use foreach loop like this?   foreach(DataRow item in dv.Rows) ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Pls see